# Spamassasin disable Email from external to all groups except

Tags: spamassassin

I would like to have a spamassasin rule that by default disables all external Emails to groups with exclusion of only a few groups. Thus `someone@external.example` should not be able to `users@internal.example`.
While internal users should be able to those groups.

Only some group address should be possible for external usage
`someone@external.example` is allowed to email `SalesTeam@internal.example`.

Answer (score 0):

Entirely misdirected mail (or even, for the outside world, nonexisting addresses) is a separate concept from spam. This is generally not something you want to skew your spam filtering metrics - so let the mail server reject them.

For postfix, you probably want to utilize the fact that the right hand side of `access` maps can lead to another lookup:

1. Insert a map declaring what is a restricted recipient

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
 [..]
 reject_non_fqdn_recipients
 check_recipient_access pcre:/etc/postfix/access_recipient.pcre
 [..]
```

2. Add a new restrictions class defining who can email those restricted addresses

```
    smtpd_restriction_classes =
     smtpd_restriction_sender_internal
     [..]
    smtpd_restriction_sender_internal =
     check_recipient_access pcre:/etc/postfix/maps/access_sender_internal.pcre
```

3. Define who is a rectricted recipient in `/etc/postfix/access_recipient.pcre`:

```
    /SalesTeam@internal\.example$/  DUNNO
    /receives.external@internal\.example$/  DUNNO
    /@internal\.example/                    smtpd_restriction_sender_internal
```

4. Define who can email those recipients in `/etc/postfix/maps/access_sender_internal.pcre`

```
    /@internal\.example$/                         DUNNO
    /can.send.from.external@partner\.example$/    DUNNO
    /./                                           DEFER 4.2.0 Internal Recipient
```

Note that the order of `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` matters here - if you were to order any whitelisting mechanism before the new access lookup, it would be circumvented.
Note also that this filters based on `sender` - if you for some reason accept external mail claiming to be originating from you, then filtering based on `permit_sasl_authenticated` or [`permit_mynetworks` may be more appropriate](https://serverfault.com/questions/871989/postfix-restrict-incoming-emails-on-a-specific-adress-to-adress-of-the-same-doma), lest the otherwise restricted groups can be sent mail to if merely claiming to be an internal sender.